# Calling ajax function from another js script

Tags: ajax

I have a ajax function that is called by button tag

```
<button id="of_save" type="button" class="button-primary">
     <?php echo __('Save All Changes', 'optionsframework');?>
</button>

$('#of_save').live('click',function() {
...
...
...
}};
```

The problem is that theme author put a single button on top of settings page and a million of settings, so every time I want to hit save, I must scroll whole page.

I found a little JS script that intercept CTRL+S or another browser combination and is working wonderful
http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts

The problem is I don't know how to call the ajax function from this JS

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+Shift+X",function() {
alert("Hi there!");
    // not working...
     live('click',function());

});
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated. Avoid it unless you have a particularly good reason to.

Comment: it is the theme originally function that I need to call